# 'import' statement not working in script in rendered HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm developing a express application and Im trying to do the below thing and I keep getting the same error over and over - "GET http://localhost:3000/javascript/module2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

Could someone please point out to me what mistake I am committing and point me in the right direction? Below is my code -

**Module1.js**

```
import theFunc from "./module2";
console.log("In module 1");
theFunc();
```

**Module2.js**

```
export default function theFunc() {
console.log("from module 2");
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
 <body>
   Should show the result in console.
  <script type="module" src="./javascript/module1.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a ton in advance! :)

Answer (score 38):

The message points out the issue, but it's still pretty easy to miss.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/javascript/module2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

is the issue, because instead of

```
http://localhost:3000/javascript/module2
```

the URL is actually

```
http://localhost:3000/javascript/module2.js
```

with a `.js` extension.

The issue is that

```
import theFunc from "./module2";
```

should be

```
import theFunc from "./module2.js";
```

Comment: I have to ask, you are correct, but why would that be the case? I thought if it was a `.js` extension, it did not require it on an import inside an `index.js` file.

Comment: Node can add `.js` automatically because it can look at the filesystem and if there is no file matching the given name, it will try again with `.js` appended on. A browser could technically see a 404 and then try again with `.js` appended onto the URL, but that would mean that every import without a `.js` would have to do twice as many requests, which would be horrible for performance.

Comment: Quite difficult to find this information on the internet. Thanks a lot, @loganfsmyth.

Comment: Thanks this is was very useful for me.

Comment: Thanks, auto import by ide isnt corect

Answer (score 1):

The import and export statements belong to **ES6** therfore you need to use a transpiler like Babel.
You second option is to use `require` which the equivalent in ES5:

First add this script to the head of your html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Change these lines:

```
import theFunc from "./module2";
```

becomes

```
 var theFunc = require("./module2");
```

& this one too:

```
export default function theFunc() {
console.log("from module 2");
}
```

becomes:

```
function theFunc() {
console.log("from module 2");
}
module.exports = theFunc;
```

Comment: Hi Melchia, 
I tried out your solution and I have a new error which is again causing a new problem - 
`"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at module1.js"`
Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you're using this in your browser. You need to import require